# Object already exists with Entity Framework Core initial migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm in the process of learning how to use EF and I'm attempting to do an initial create migration using EF core.
When I run `Update-Database` after running `Add-Migration InitialCreate` I receive an error:

> There is already an object named 'Customers' in the database.

The other SO questions concerning this issue typically had the person delete their db and do an initial migration to fix this issue. Because this is my initial create I'm unsure how to proceed.

I have no DB with a customers object, so I'm unsure why EF is telling me that there is already an object named 'Customers' when trying to create my new DB.

Now although I get this error it appears my tables are created for the new DB but I don't know what the cause of this error is.

I've deleted the new DB and and the Migrations folder and tried running the same commands as before in the console.

`Add-Migration InitialCreate`
`Update-Database`

I still receive the same error. Below are my models, context and startup.
Any insight into why I'm receiving this error would be much appreciated.

**Customer Model**

```
 public class Customer
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [MaxLength( 254 )]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [MaxLength( 15 )]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LodgingDates> LodgingDates { get; set; } =
        new List<LodgingDates>( );

    [Required]
    public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 100 )]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 60 )]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 9 )]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 55 )]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool ReceiveEmailNotifications { get; set; }
 }
```

**CreditCard Model**

```
public class CreditCard
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int CreditCardId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 19 )]
    [CreditCard]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 4 )]
    public int Ccv { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 100 )]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 60 )]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 9 )]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 55 )]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string StateOrProvince { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

**LodgingDates Model**

```
public class LodgingDates
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int LodgingDatesId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }


    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; } 
}
```

**Context**

```
public sealed class LodgingCrmContext : DbContext
{
    public LodgingCrmContext( DbContextOptions<LodgingCrmContext> options ) 
        : base( options )
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LodgingDates> LodgingDates { get; set; } 
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        services.AddDbContext<LodgingCrmContext>( options =>
            options.UseSqlServer( Configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I restarted VS and navigated over to the `LodgingCrmContext` and noticed that the constructor had `Database.EnsureCreated( );` in it. This was something I had removed earlier today. But when I restarted VS there it was in the ctor again (weird).

Once I removed `Database.EnsureCreated( );` and rebuilt, my initial create migration worked.

The `Database.EnsureCreated( );` was causing the Customers table to be created twice. This would also explain why the DB was being created (with the correct tables) and why I was seeing:

> There is already an object named 'Customers' in the database.